# Yii1 CGridView(Yii-Booster): How to change filter key(filterVal) in TbGridView(based on CGridView)?

Tags: php, cgridview, yii-booster, cactivedataprovider, yii1.x

I am using yii-booster(4.0.1) TbGridView(extends CGridView) and need to change the filter variable name in _REQUEST($_POST, $_GET) for filter function.
In my grid, I have filter functionality and when I press enter after entering some words in the filter input, an ajax request will sent for server. in this request in $_REQUEST I have:

```
array
(
    'page' => '1'
    'wsi_it_model_Asset' => array
    (
        'user' => 'eghlima'
        'createdAt' => ''
        'serial' => ''
        'brand' => ''
        'model' => ''
        'assetType' => ''
        'assigned' => ''
        'location' => ''
        'status' => ''
    )
)
```

My question is how can I change **wsi_it_model_Asset** in the request created by CGridView. 
I know that I should do it through a parameter in *CActiveDataProvider* when I am creating the dataProvider but I can not find it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 24 Jan** 
I found my code from another project, as you can see I can change the `key` for `sort` and `pagination`, I need something look like for filtering key;

```
return new \CActiveDataProvider($this->applicant, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageVar' => 'p', // <<<<< pagination var
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ),
            'sort' => array(
                'sortVar' => 's', // <<<<< sorting var
                'defaultOrder' => 't.firstName ASC',
                'attributes' => array(
                    '*'
                )

            ),
        ));
```

So for pagination, the request which is posting from client to server will be:

```
array
(
    'p' => '7' // <<<<<< page changed to `p`
    'wsi_it_model_Asset' => array
    (
        'user' => 'eghlima'
        'createdAt' => ''
        'serial' => ''
        'brand' => ''
        'model' => ''
        'assetType' => ''
        'assigned' => ''
        'location' => ''
        'status' => ''
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are meaning, but I give it a try.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'value' => '$data->theValue',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'myWish'),
        ),
    )
));
```

And then in your model you add a virtual attribute

```
public function getMyWish()
   {
      return 'Your dream answere';
   }
```

And in your $model->search() add:

```
$criteria->compare('$data->theValue', $this->myWish,true);
```

Something like this check a very good tutorial on virtual attributes: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/

Comment: no, this is not the answer. 
look; you wrote:
    'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'myWish'),
When you use model in yii1, it uses the class name for element, and in my case it is Asset with namespace wsi\it\model, so yii1 will pick wsi_it_model_Asset as the prefix for the element name and id, and whenever it wants to send a request, all params will have this as the prefix.
but I am sure, there should be a solution to change this variable!